# Redirect to a custom Lightning tab via JS

Tags: lightning

Any one know how to "cleanly" redirect to a custom Lightning tab via JS?  I was able to use e.force.naviageToURL to navigate to the tab. But the tab's url currently looks something like this:

> https://#######.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6ZmxleGlwYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJ2YWx1ZXMiOnsiZmxleGlQYWdlRGV2ZWxvcGVyTmFtZSI6Ik9uZV9QZW5za2VfU2VhcmNoIiwibGFiZWwiOiJPbmUgUGVuc2tlIFNlYXJjaCIsImljb25VcmwiOiJodHRwczovL3BlbnNrZS0tUUEuY3MyMC5teS5zYWxlc2ZvcmNlLmNvbS9pbWcvaWNvbi90NHYzNS9jdXN0b20vY3VzdG9tMzlfMTIwLnBuZyIsImljb25Db2xvciI6IjRmYmU3NSJ9fSwidCI6MTQ3NzU4MDQ4OTQxNn0%3D

I'm not sure if that URL is static, or if it changes between prod/sandbox or if it changes for different user sessions.  I was wondering if it would be possible to reference the tab using it's name, then if there would be like a a "generateURL" method or something I can use to generate the above string.

btw, when I say "custom lightning tab", I mean these things:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_flexipage_tabs.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Thanks